# Filtering user asset FeatureCollection by column containing date using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to filter imported AIS data (https://marinecadastre.gov/AIS/) by time, as ground truth for ship detection using SAR images. The imported CSV stores the date in a column ["BaseDateTime"], which can be shown in the bottom image and GEE code link. The format seems to be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`.

My problems are the following:

1. GEE doesn't let me simply filter something in a "column" that isn't a "property" of a `FeatureCollection`
2. The "BaseDateTime" values are not in `ee.Date` format, so reducing by column is difficult.

How do I select the AIS points that would correspond to the time a SAR image was taken?

[image]

Link Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ec4c3c9f7f983cc99ed3daee44f47bf5

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//SAR Data
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                  .filterDate('2020-06-30', '2020-07-01')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
                  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));

var listOfImages = dataset.toList(dataset.size()); // 29 images


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///AIS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Importing Feature Collection 

var ais = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sheilababer/AIS_2020_06_30').filterBounds(roi);

Map.addLayer(ais);


//Treating "BaseDateTime" as a Property yields errors: 

var dayRange = ee.Number(0.08) //wanting the AIS data to be within 2 hours of SAR

var feats = ais.map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Feature(feat);
  var date = ee.Date(feat.get('BaseDateTime'));
  var dateRange = ee.DateRange(date.advance(-(dayRange/2), 'day'), date.advance(dayRange/2, 'day'));
  var image = dataset.filterDate(dateRange).mean();
  var data = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), feat.geometry(), 500);
  return ee.Feature(feat.setMulti(data))
});

var date_col = ['BaseDateTime']

//Trying to reduce the feature collection by column also yields errors,
//probably because date is parsed as a string:

print(ais.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  selectors: ['BaseDateTime'],
}));


print(ais['BaseDateTime'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your collections aren't shared, but because those dates are in ISO format, you can simply filter the strings:

```
var ais = ee.FeatureCollection('users/sheilababer/AIS_2020_06_30')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filter('BaseDateTime > '2020-06-30' && BaseDateTime < '2020-07-01'")
```